# AWS Api Gateway Post to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

i need help with Response Body Template. 
I am Using POST to "PutItem" in dynamoDB using APIGateway directly(No lambda).

The new item is added successfully but the response is Empty at 200

What I need is 
1 - New row data 
2 - Status 
3 - Message

```
{
  "data": [],
  "status": "Success",
  "message": "Updated Succesfully"
}
```

without using lambda...Is this possible?

I tried many stuffs i.e.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{"templateId": "$elem.templateId.S",
"templateFileName": "$elem.templateFileName.S"}
```

but its showing null.

Here is my log when i run Test @API Gateway

Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Endpoint request body after transformations:

```
{ 
    "TableName": "xyz-mobilehub-9260364_Template_Table",
    "Item": {
    "templateId": {
            "S": "APIGateway"
            },
        "templateFileName": {
            "S": "breaking-news-story-01-18-2016"
            },
        "templateName": {
            "S": "Just Saying Thank You"
        },
        "templateType": {
            "S": "I really enjoyed this story!!"
        }
    }
}
```

Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Sending request to https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=PutItem
Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Received response. Integration latency: 33 ms
Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {}
Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response headers: {Server=Server, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=RE631UNS84TACTMP4TE752UK0BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, x-amz-crc32=2745614147, Content-Length=2, Date=Sat, 17 Feb 2018 06:22:17 GMT, Content-Type=application/x-amz-json-1.0}
Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Method response body after transformations:

```
{
"templateId": "",
"templateFileName": "",
}
```

Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5a87ca19-62a291f9a923480f5c62884f, Content-Type=application/json}
Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Successfully completed execution
Sat Feb 17 06:22:18 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 200

Answer (score 1):

Go to Integration Response in you API Gateway and give the response in the way you want. Please see below screenshots,

[image]

Select Integration Response,

[image]

under Generate Template provide your JSON data

Comment: how can i set different response for inserted and updated etc?